# How to determine parameters range?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, temperature

I am into running some leaching experiments and wanted to study the effect of different parameters on my dissolution results. But I am confused with determining the parameters range. For example, I wanted to investigate the effect of temperature on my results. But I am not sure in which temperature range I should run my experiments. Should I test different temperatures (or other parameters as well) and see the change in the results and if by changing more in the level of that parameter, no change happened, so I can say for example that level is one of my upper of lower range?

The system I am going to study is: Oxidation of arsenic bearing sulfide (AsS) in aquatic leaching medium. I want to see the effect of different parameters; pH, Eh, temperature, oxidant agent on the As dissolution behavior. However, choosing the right range for each of these parameters are my main concern.

I am going to derive the equilibrium state for my mineral dissolution (so I can derive chemical stoichiometry) and then I should study the dissolution rate of my goal element (As).  I am going to study both synthesic (pure) ore and real ore from mine location, therefore I asked my question as a general one.

Comment: Can you provide more information, such as what the actual chemical system is? As it stands, your question is very broad.

Comment: Your question is sort of a mess. (A) Are you trying to study the kinetics or the equilibrium for the reactions? (B) Is this for some sort of leaching from ore or "pure" AsS? (C) You need to first design an experiment to see what factors are important (D) Given (C) you vary each factor of interest over a range to try to fit appropriate constants to the data.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I am going to derive the equilibrium state for my mineral dissolution (So I can derive chemical stoichiometry) and then I should study the dissolution rate of my goal element (As). You are right about the purity, but as I am going to study both synthesis (pure) ore and real ore from mine location, I asked my question as a general one.

Comment: Well a great method used is to do a [Design of experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_experiments)